# How do I query and array of object where the object is a nested object?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is a document in my mongodb:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "64c7d4d7711f2703209bd076"
    },
    "identifiers": {
        "pCode": "P3842"
    },
    "contact": [
        {
            "phone": {
                "home": "000000",
                "work": "000000 Ext 838",
                "mobile": "0000000",
                "primary": "000000"
            },
            "email": {
                "home": "bla@hotmail.com",
                "work": null,
                "primary": "bla@hotmail.com"
            },
        },
    ],
    "children": [
        {
            "student": {
                "$oid": "64c7d48e711f2703209bd075"
            },
            "relationship": "Father",
            "billPayer": true,
            "courtOrder": false
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "createdDTM": "2018-02-10 07:35:45.000000",
        "updatedDTM": "2022-02-10 12:12:36.000000",
        "lastModifiedDTM": "2023-07-31 15:50:22"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I am trying to check in the `contact` array for the `email` object if any of the keys(`home`, `work`, `primary`) has email id which equals to `"bla@hotmail.com"`

I tried to run using `$elemMatch` but I get a `null` as the result.

```json
 {
    contact: { $elemMatch: { email: "bla@hotmail.com" } },
 }
```

Can't figure out where I am wrong.

Update: tried this query using `$or` which gives me the result but I would like to know if there are other queries as well which can be better.

also fixed indentation

```
{$or: [
        {
            "contact.email.home": "bla@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
            "contact.email.work": "bla@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
            "contact.email.primary": "bla@hotmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Consider that your `email` object is fixed (which you know there will have `home`, `work` and `primary` fields in it, you can work with your `$or` and specify all the available fields. With your current approach is much simpler and better performance-wise compared to my proposed approach. Otherwise, you may look for `$objectToArray` to convert key-value pair into objects. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yOhbIZxZtCU)

Comment: your "fixed" query is fine, also there is no better way as you have to access all 3 fields.